# Multiple bar graph with ggplot2 and shiny R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot a multiple bar graph for a customer satisfaction data set using Ggplot on R Shiny. Satisfaction varies from 1 to 5, where 1 being the lowest and 5 being the highest. This is how it looks like: (This is a sample of the original data set)

```
Satisfaction_Level <- c(4   ,4  ,5  ,5  ,3  ,4  ,4  ,4  ,4  ,5  ,1  ,4  ,1  ,3  ,4  ,4  ,1  ,4  ,4  ,1  ,4  ,4  ,4  ,4  ,2  ,4  ,2  ,4  ,3  ,1)

Location <- c("C"   ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"B"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"A"    ,"B"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"B"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"B"    ,"C"    ,"B"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"B"    ,"B"    ,"B"    ,"B"    ,"B"    ,"B"    ,"B")
```

With the below code, I was able to generate this graph:

[image: Overall satisfaction bar graph]

```
#satisfaction counts
satisCounts <- data.frame(table(mydata[,1]))
colnames(satisCounts) <- c("satisLevel", "satisCount")
satisCounts$perc3 <- as.character(round(100* satisCounts$satisCount / sum(satisCounts$satisCount)), 2)
satisCounts$lab3 <- paste(satisCounts$satisCount, paste("(",satisCounts$perc3,"%)",sep=""),sep=" ")

output$graph3 <- renderPlot({
  satisCounts %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=satisLevel, y=satisCount)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=satisLevel)) +
    labs(y= "Customer count", x="Satisfaction Level") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#de425b", "#f2955a", "#ffe48f", "#a9b957", "#488f31")) +
    labs(fill = "Satisfaction Level") +
    geom_text(aes(label=lab3), vjust=-.5)
})
```

But what I actully want is to make this a multiple bar graph where all the satisfaction levels broken down by the location. Could you please help me fix this? Thank you!

Comment: could you kindly make your example reproducible - most importantly, what is the object 'mydata'

Comment: My objective is to create a Shiny dashboard using the data set. (Above data set is a sample of the original data set) One of the graphs I'm trying to create is the satisfaction level of each location. Once I'm succeeded in this, I'm trying to make this graph interactive so that when the location is selected from a drop down, the graph renders accordingly :)

Answer (score 2):

From your question is is not clear how the final plot should look like. One option would be to use facetting. Another option would be to use a dodged bar chart. But the basis idea is to first compue counts by loacation and satisfaction levels. Have a look at this.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Satisfaction_Level<-c(4 ,4  ,5  ,5  ,3  ,4  ,4  ,4  ,4  ,5  ,1  ,4  ,1  ,3  ,4  ,4  ,1  ,4  ,4  ,1  ,4  ,4  ,4  ,4  ,2  ,4  ,2  ,4  ,3  ,1)

Location <- c("C"  ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"B"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"A"    ,"B"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"B"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"B"    ,"C"    ,"B"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"C"    ,"B"    ,"B"    ,"B"    ,"B"    ,"B"    ,"B"    ,"B")

df <- data.frame(
  satisLevel = Satisfaction_Level,
  Location = Location,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

#satisfaction counts
# satisCounts <- data.frame(table(mydata[,1]))
# colnames(satisCounts) <- c("satisLevel", "satisCount")
# satisCounts$perc3 <- as.character(round(100* satisCounts$satisCount / sum(satisCounts$satisCount)), 2)
# satisCounts$lab3 <- paste(satisCounts$satisCount, paste("(",satisCounts$perc3,"%)",sep=""),sep=" ")

satisCounts <- df %>% 
  count(Location, satisLevel, name = "satisCount") %>% 
  mutate(satisLevel = factor(satisLevel))

satisCounts$perc3 <- as.character(round(100* satisCounts$satisCount / sum(satisCounts$satisCount)), 2)
satisCounts$lab3 <- paste(satisCounts$satisCount, paste("(",satisCounts$perc3,"%)",sep=""),sep=" ")

# Option 1: Use facetting
satisCounts %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=satisLevel, y=satisCount)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=satisLevel)) +
  labs(y= "Customer count", x="Satisfaction Level") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#de425b", "#f2955a", "#ffe48f", "#a9b957", "#488f31")) +
  labs(fill = "Satisfaction Level") +
  geom_text(aes(label=lab3), vjust=-.5) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Location, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# Option 2: Dodged bar chart
satisCounts %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Location, y=satisCount, fill=satisLevel)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
  labs(y= "Customer count", x="Satisfaction Level") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#de425b", "#f2955a", "#ffe48f", "#a9b957", "#488f31")) +
  labs(fill = "Satisfaction Level") +
  geom_text(aes(label=lab3), vjust=-.5, position = position_dodge2(.9, preserve = "single"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>